# what is the nodejs code for this curl command

Tags: node.js, curl

I can successfully execute this curl command from a Unix shell script and I can see output in C:\Users\OutputFile.csv. What is the equivalent code in NodeJS

```
curl -k  -v  --user 'helloworld:hello_password' 
--header 'Accept: application/vnd.myDMS-dms-api+json; version=1' 
-X POST  'https://DMS.com:3001/download/csv' 
--data header=true  -o C:\Users\OutputFile.csv
```

I tried using the Online curl to nodeJS converter and it has generated the following NodeJs code:-

```
    var request = require('request');
    var headers = {
       'Accept': 'application/vnd.myDMS-dms-api+json; version=1'
     };
    var options = {
        url: 'https://DMS.com:3001/download/csv',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: headers,
        auth: {
            'user': 'helloworld',
            'pass': 'hello_password'
            }
     };

   function callback(error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            console.log(body);
          }
     }
   request(options, callback);
```

However, when I run this NodeJS code it does not show any output. Also how can I get this output to C:\Users\OutputFile.csv

Comment: Just to close the thread: Added error handling and saw that it was not able to connect to host due to missing port number. Added the port number and was able to connect to the host.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the response isn't return before the script is terminated. You would want the request to be asynchronous:

You can use [request-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise)

Here's an example

```
var rp = require('request-promise');

function someFunction() {
    let options = {
        url: `someURL`,
        method: 'POST',
        body: {
           some: 'payload'
          },
        json: true 
    };
    return rp(options);
}
```

This will await the response.

Answer (score 0):

A simple version of your API parameters using `request-promise`:

```
var rp = require('request-promise');

function downloadFile() {
    var options = {
        uri: 'https://DMS.com:3001/download/csv',
        method: 'POST',
        auth: {
            user: 'helloworld',
            pass: 'hello_password',
            sendImmediately: true
        },
        headers: {
            Accept:'application/vnd.myDMS-dms-api+json; version=1'
        },
        form: {
           'header': 'true'
        }
    };

    rp(options)
        .then(function (body) {
            console.log('Downloaded body was %d long', repos.length);
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.log(err)
        });
}

downloadFile()
```

Comment: Thankyou for the reply. Would this be the exact conversion of the curl cmd that I have mentioned in my query? The URL (is a document management system) and should return the csv file C:\Users\OutputFile.csv.